# Add Css to an element with specific class but multiple class names present

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to add css to a 'td' in a Table that is part of the [fullcalender](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/)

The day cells have classes added fc-day0 to fc-day41 
td element looks like this:

```
<td class="fc-mon fc-widget-content fc-day1">
```

I tried following:

```
$("td").filter("fc-day1")
       .css("background", "red");

$("td").find("fc-day1")
       .css("background", "red");

$("td").find($('td[class*=".fc-day1"]'))
       .css("background", "red");
```

I appreciate your help =)

Comment: just adding a `.` to your selector before the classname should do the trick (for the first two). as it is jquery things `fc-day1` is a tag name...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want to filter out your collection of td and find all who has the class fc-day1 then use filter with a css selector:

```
$("td").filter(".fc-day1")
    .css("background", "red");
```

Comment: thx for correctin my code -.-'
are there speed differnece between adeno's solution and the filter function?
(the class exist only once on the page...)

Comment: There is almost certainly no noticeable speed differences but there will be some. Try them both and see which you prefer.

Comment: I think adeneo code should be faster (in IE) because both selectors need to go to sizzle anyway and with adeneo´s code it only goes to sizzle once. its an easy miss when you have looked at your code too long @LightMonk ;)

Answer (score 1):

To target a `TD` with the class `fc-day1` just do:

```
$("td.fc-day1").css("background", "red");
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/XdgSD/1/)

Comment: @adeneo: can you tell me how would he apply the red bg color to the classes that start with fc-day? I tried this but it didn't work: http://jsfiddle.net/Hitman666/XdgSD/2/

Comment: The starts with selector is `^`, but it only mathes if the value of the attribute matches exactly, so it will read all the classes and won't work. You could do [this](http://jsfiddle.net/XdgSD/3/), but that will match if the string of classnames contains that string anywhere, so a filter [solution](http://jsfiddle.net/XdgSD/4/) is probably better. For just selecting a classname the regular way, using a filter is completely unnecessary, and I'd go so far as to call it bad practice.

Comment: @adeneo: thx! heh, now i think i should have posted this as a question.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need jquery.

In a file css:

```
<style>
table td .fc-day1{
  background:red;
}
</style>
```

Regards

Comment: I ask this question because i have some event calculation in the back ;-)
I know how css works =)